# Emma doesn't provide code coverage across projects

Tags: java, ant, code-coverage, emma

I was wondering if any of you EMMA users have encountered this issue.

Basically I have multiple projects each with different build.xml ANT scripts that are all called from one main ANT script individually. The code is covered appropriately but when a JUnit method calls another method in a different project, that external method call is not covered by EMMA.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Can anyone spare any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're pointing your unit tests at the instrumented classes for the external method call?

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you with Emma.  But what you need is a code coverage tool that can combine test coverage data from multiple projects into a coherent whole.

SD's test coverage tools (including the one for Java) can  do this out of the box.  This allows one to keep lots of "projects" that each make up a significant part of a much larger (meta)project (e.g., Eclipse!), and get a picture of coverage of the metaproject.
We've uses this to handle systems with 45,000 compileable Java programs.
They can also combine data from multiple test coverage runs on a single project into coherent information for that project.

See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/index.html

(Hi Kurt).